# how to convert 23/1/17 to 23/01/2017 in a row of csv file with unix?

Tags: date, unix, format

I am looking for how to convert all dates in a csv file row into this format ? example I want to convert 23/1/17 to 23/01/2017

I use unix

thank you

my file is like this :

23/1/17
17/08/18
1/1/2
5/6/03
18/05/2019

and I want this :

23/01/2017
17/08/2018
01/01/2002
05/06/2003
18/05/2019

Comment: Have you tried a simple `sed` replacement? You can match on `\([[:digit:]]\+\)/\([[:digit:]]\+\)/\([[:digit:]]\+\)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer I tried but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I used `date_samples.csv` as my test data:

> 23/1/17,17/08/18,1/1/02,5/6/03,18/05/2019

```
cat date_samples.csv | tr "," "\n" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}{print $2,$1,$3}' | \
while read CMD; do
    date -d $CMD +%d/%m/%Y >> temp
done; cat temp | tr "\n" "," > converted_dates.csv ; rm temp; truncate -s-1 converted_dates.csv
```

Output:

```
23/01/2017,17/08/2018,01/01/2002,05/06/2003,18/05/2019
```

This portion of the code converts your "," to new lines and makes your input DD/MM/YY to MM/DD/YY, since the `date` command does not accept date inputs of DD/MM/YY. It then loops through re-arranged dates and convert them to DD/MM/YYYY format and temporarily stores them in `temp`.

```
cat date_samples.csv | tr "," "\n" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}{print $2,$1,$3}' | \
while read CMD; do
    date -d $CMD +%d/%m/%Y >> temp
done;
```

This line `cat temp | tr "\n" "," > converted_dates.csv ; rm temp;  truncate -s-1 converted_dates.csv` converts the new line back to "," and puts the output to `converted_dates.csv` and deletes `temp`.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk -F, '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { split($i,map,"/");if (length(map[3])==1) { map[3]="0"map[3] } "date -d \""map[2]"/"map[1]"/"map[3]"\" \"+%d/%m/%y\"" | getline dayte;close("date -d \""map[2]"/"map[1]"/"map[3]"\" \"+%d/%m/%y\"");$i=dayte }OFS="," }1' file
```

Explanation:

```
awk -F, '{ 
           for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { 
             split($i,map,"/"); # Loop through each comma separated field and split into the array map using "/" as the field seperator
             if (length(map[3])==1) { 
               map[3]="0"map[3] # If the year is just one digit, pad out with prefix 0
             } 
             "date -d \""map[2]"/"map[1]"/"map[3]"\" \"+%d/%m/%y\"" | getline dayte; # Run date command on day month and year and read result into variable dayte
             close("date -d \""map[2]"/"map[1]"/"map[3]"\" \"+%d/%m/%y\""); # Close the date execution pipe
             $i=dayte # Replace the field for the dayte  variable
           }
           OFS="," # Set the output field seperator
          }1' file
```